Generalization of the Lagrange undetermined multiplier method
Section 6.6 of the book Classical Dynamics of Particles and Systems treats Euler's equations with auxiliary conditions. It proves the method of Lagrange undetermined for the case of two functions.
in order to extermize the integral $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(y,y',z,z';x)\, dx$, with the constraint $g(y,z;x) = 0$,
you need to solve the following equations:
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} + \lambda(x)\frac{\partial g}{\partial y} = 0$
$\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z'} + \lambda(x)\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = 0$
$g(y,z;x) = 0$
and then it generalizes it to $m$ functions and $n$ constraints with these equations:
for every $1 \le i\le m$: $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_i'} + \sum _j\lambda_j(x)\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_i} = 0$
for every $1 \le j \le n$ : $g(y_i;x) = 0$
I can't figure out how this generalization is done. Is it necessary to assume that $n = m -1$? Or can it also be done with less quantities of $n$?
I tried to prove it myself for the case of $n  = m-1$:
for every $j$: $\displaystyle\sum _k\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_k} \eta_k = 0$
so for a specific $i$ and for every $j$ we'll have: $\displaystyle\sum _{k\neq i}\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_k} \eta_k = -\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_i} \eta_i$
So if we define $\displaystyle A(i)_{jk} = \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_k}$(since $A$ does not include $\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_i}$ in specific, it is dependent on $i$) and $F_k = \displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial y_k} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y_k'} $, we'll have:
$\displaystyle \eta_k = -\sum_j A^{-1}_{kj} \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_i} \eta_i$
and the equation $\displaystyle \int_a^b\sum_kF_k\eta_k\,dx = 0$ will turn into $\displaystyle \int_a^b(F_i - \sum_{k\neq i} F_k \sum_j A^{-1}_{kj}\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_k})\eta_i\,dx= \int_a^b(F_i - \sum_j \sum_{k\neq i} F_k A^{-1}_{kj}\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_k})\eta_i\,dx$
and now if we define $\displaystyle -\lambda_j(x) = \sum_{k\neq i} F_k A^{-1}_{kj}$, we'll have:
$\displaystyle F_i + \sum_j \lambda_j \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial y_i}$
However, this way, unlike the form of the equations in the book, $\lambda_j(x)$ also depends  on $i$ as $A$ is different for every $i$. Is this proof correct and if yes, how can it be proved that, by this definition, $\lambda_j(x)$ is same for every $i$?

Think of the case $m=2$ and $n=3$ with unknown functions $y,z$ and conditions $g_1(y(x),z(x),x) =0, g_2(y(x),z(x),x)=0, g_3(y(x),z(x),x)=0$. Do you think you will always have a solution?

I meant other amounts of n that are less than m - 1.

To show how to properly generalize, start with the augmented Lagrangian then proceed from there: $L(y,z) = \int f~dx + \int \boldsymbol{\lambda}^T\boldsymbol{g}~dx$. The number of components of $\boldsymbol{\lambda}$ must be equal to the number of constraints as the Lagrange multiplier is defined as something lying in the dual space of the constraint
